# Floating action button cannot be found on emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, floating-action-button

I have created a layout with an `ImageView`, `VideoView` and a floating action button. My idea is to keep on showing the floating action button above the `VideoView` and `ImageView`.

Below is my XML code and it looks like the floating action button is hidden behind `ImageView` and `VideoView`. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    tools:context="com.serv24.eframe.FullscreenActivity" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:rippleColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` for easier implementation in your case. You just have to put the elements below some other elements to go on top of the elements above in your layout. I am sharing a version of your layout using `RelativeLayout`. Hope that helps!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:rippleColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The items added in your FrameLayout are added on top of each other, so the newest added item is above the one before.

In your case you first added the ProgressBar, then the FloatingActionButton which is displayed above the ProgressBar, after that you added the VideoView which is displayed above the FloatingActionButton (if the VideoView is full screen it will hide everything that you placed before) and lastly the ImageView which is displayed on top of everything else.

You can think of it like placing paper sheets on top of each other on a table.

So to have your fab displayed, you should put it in the last position in your xml (after the ImageView).